# Remove negative/blank input from key value pair - Python

Tags: python, tuples

I am mapping values as `(Key, Tuple 2 value)`.
And I am trying to write a code in python to read the key values and remove invalid input(input containing negative values and blank fields).

1) How to send the key value pair argument to the python function? Or should I create the pair once in the python function?

2) How to check for invalid values?

This is the subset of list of values I have.

```
**KEY** **VAL** **VAL**  
196 242 -3  
186 302 3   
22      1   
244 51  2   
166 346 1   
298 474 4   
115     2   
253 465 -5  
305 451 3   
6   86  3
```

I am new to big data and python. Thanks for the help.
code -

```
input = sc.textFile("file:///home/<>/Downloads/Sample.txt")  
input1 =input.map(lambda x: (x.split("\t")[0],x.split("\t")[1],x.split("\t")[2]))  
input2 = input1.map (lambda x: cleanup(x))  
def cleanup(x):  
    for tok in x:  
       key = x[0]  
       value = x[1], x[2]
    return (key,value)
```

Comment: how does your code look so far?

Comment: Please update your post with your code, don't put it in a comment!  Don't call a variable `input`, it is the name of a built-in.  What is `sc`?

Comment: Please add your code to the original question.

Comment: Aside from your bad use of `input`, your code seems reasonable (all code could be improved in some way).  Now I'm puzzled:  what you are actually asking?  Do you get an error with this code?  Is the output different to what you expect?

Comment: I now want to eliminate the key value pairs that have negative and blank values. I am not able to work on the individual values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
a = tuple(map(int, input().split()))

if len(a) != 3:
    print('Value Missing')

if not all(x >= 0 for x in a):
    print('Negative')
```